# Separate Ember Addon from vendor.js file to a separate file

Tags: npm, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm using a "core"-addon which contains logic that is used in multiple "boilerplate" - ember applications, when I build a boilerplate-application, the addon code is added to the "vendor.js" file found in the "assets"-folder. Is there a way I can make this code build to a separate "my-addon-vendor.js" file?

While browsing I found others with the same need, but an answer has yet to be found.

My "core"-addon is linked to my "boilerplate"-project using "npm link my-core-addon".

Thanks in advance

Versions:

- Ember Version: 3.5.0
- Ember CLI: 3.5.0
- Node: 8.11.3
- npm: 5.6.0

Comment: is there purely for optimization reasons? It would help to understand your need for this because there might be alternative solutions.

Comment: Indeed for optimization and debugging reasons. We want our own custom addon(s) separated from our vendor file which is becoming very large.

Comment: you might have best luck https://discordapp.com/invite/zT3asNS joining the discord and asking in the `ember-cli` community chat. Your question is nuanced and it'd be easier to answer understanding more deeply the reasons

Comment: https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/will-code-splitting-per-ember-addon-be-possible-next/14548/5

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
  var qrScannerWorker = new Funnel(
    'node_modules/qr-scanner/', {
      include: ['qr-scanner-worker.min.js'],
      destDir: '/libraries/qr-scanner/'
    }
  );
```

https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/emberclear/blob/master/packages/frontend/ember-cli-build.js#L139

this won't work for addons, but it'll work for underlying dependencies. So, if an addon is doing the bundling for you, you may want to do it yourself.